# java anonymous statement or what it is called?

Tags: java

I would like to understand what is this called. I saw this program in oracle website. I have kept breakpoint and saw this statment is called after static block and before constructor is called.

What is signifiance of this statement ?

```
{
    System.out.print("y ");
}
```

In this code :

```
public class Sequence {
    Sequence() {
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    {
        System.out.print("y ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sequence().go();
    }

    void go() {
        System.out.print("g ");
    }

    static {
        System.out.print("x ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an instance initialization block, and it's executed whenever an instance is created.

Comment: Thanks for response, what is advantage of this block over constructor .. even the constructor is called every time an instance is created. ideal scenario when we use it?

Comment: Well, if you have many constructors, the instance initializer block would be called regardless of which constructor you call. It's similar to having a helper method that's being called at the beginning of all the constructors.

Comment: That makes sense ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static {
        System.out.print("x ");
    }
```

Its the static block and its called whenever class is loaded. In general anonymous means which does not have any name like anonymous class are clases which does not have any name and their implementation is provided right at the place where it is required and can't be reused

```
 {
        System.out.print("y ");
    }
```

As Eran commented out ,`It's an instance initialization block, and it's executed whenever an instance is created` and is called even before constructor.

Comment: Thanks for response but i was talking about  

{
    System.out.print("y ");
}

Comment: Thanks Sach ...by the way i didn't click this answer is not useful :) .. i dont have reputation points to do that .

Comment: @Sach .. no points to accept as well .. may be need to wait until i earn some reputation points

Answer (score 0):

It is an initializer block. It is executed whenever a new instance of a class is created. Most of the time you don't really need it, because instance initialization can also be put in the constructor. The initializer block is mainly there to initialize anonymous inner classes, for which you cannot define your own constructors (because to define a constructor you need the name of the class).

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a static initialization block, or static initializer.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Personally, I prefer not to use them exactly for the reason stated in the documentation I sited.

> There is an alternative to static blocks — you can write a private
>   static method: The advantage of private static methods is that they
>   can be reused later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain whats incorrect about this answer ?

Comment: not sure who downvoted, but its not static initialization block, it is instance initialization block